# How to sign an ios phonegap app from the command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

So, I'm trying to make a whole script that would make most of the steps of running an app built from phonegapp almost automatically.

I'm actually trying to automate the process of adding certificates and provisioning profile. But I'm not even sure if it is possible or not.

I'm looking for answers using the `phonegap`commands in terminal if it is possible. If not, I'm wondering which files I would have to modify (for example in Xcode ?) in order to add these.

The point really is to run one script from the terminal, and both the certificate and the provisioning profile would be added so that the user can run on a device without having to manage anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: Its not a single line.. u will need to write script for it. Search for jenkins setup for ios build and you should find something..